# BFGMiner vs. CGMiner

Tags: mining-pools, cgminer, mining-software, bfgminer

What is the difference between BFGMiner and CGMiner in Laymen's terms?

Also, the longterm outcome will be exactly the same if mining is done with or without a pool, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bfgminer` is a fork of `cgminer`. `bfgminer` allows the use of Get Block Template (less trust in the pool), but they're otherwise functionally the same.

Comment: bfgminer is a fork of cgminer. cgminer is a fork of cpuminer.

Comment: This sounds good. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate Moving to a pool that supports it.